# any import statement to execute "out.println()"

Tags: java

I have to use import statement only to execute the following code

```
public class Interf
{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        out.println("hi");
    } 


}
```

```
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.System.out;


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        out.println("hi");
    }
```

//out.println is the real problem

Comment: You need to do a *static* import

Comment: But having said this, I do *not* recommend that you do it.